# My camera button offers me to restart the program or exit

Tags: android, camera

hi guys first time i'm asking here,i'm doing a project about country club app and at the moment i'm writing the java class of the register page.I know it might be a simple question, but i'm trying to implement couple of buttons to upload images, 1 from gallery(which is working), 2nd for camera and 3rd for switch page(just wanted to try first to see it working which it's not either).
The swap page button doesn't respond and the camera button crash the app.
in addition i cant understand if 1 "IF" in "on Activity" should do the trick for all buttons.
tried everything, i really need help from you guys.

the class extends app compat and implements view. on click and all set are set to "this". CAM REQUEST = 1313.

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bmap;
    if((requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null)){
        Uri selectImg = data.getData();
        try{
            bmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),selectImg);
            imageViewReg.setImageBitmap(bmap);
            Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this,"Image uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
            bmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageViewReg.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.galleryBtnReg:
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            break;
        case R.id.photoBtnReg:
            Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(photoIntent,CAM_REQUEST);
            break;
        case R.id.gotoBtnReg:
            Intent gotoIntent =  new Intent(RegisterPage.this, UserInfo.class);
            startActivity(gotoIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do have all permissions.

Comment: Whats the crash ? post logs